# Weka - Can't find a permissible class

Tags: java, weka

I'm integrating Weka into a plug-in I'm writing for another application.  I included weka.jar in my class path and for the most part, things seem to be working well.  Unfortunately, when I get to the point of changing the options for some classifiers, I run into problems specific to being unable to find certain classes. For example, when I try to change the name of the classifier in the AdaBoost options, I get an error that ends like so:

```
java.lang.Exception: Can't find a permissible class called: weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet
Model options set to: -P 50 -S 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet
    at weka.core.ResourceUtils.forName(ResourceUtils.java:84)
    at weka.core.Utils.forName(Utils.java:1080)
    at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.forName(AbstractClassifier.java:91)
    at weka.classifiers.SingleClassifierEnhancer.setOptions(SingleClassifierEnhancer.java:108)
    at weka.classifiers.IteratedSingleClassifierEnhancer.setOptions(IteratedSingleClassifierEnhancer.java:115)
    at weka.classifiers.RandomizableIteratedSingleClassifierEnhancer.setOptions(RandomizableIteratedSingleClassifierEnhancer.java:93)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1.setOptions(AdaBoostM1.java:375)
```

I'm thinking that this might have something to do with me using the JAR in an OSGi bundle, but I'm not sure. Any ideas? Other than this issue, I'm able to train these classifiers just fine using the default options for them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solve this problem via set all parameters via setters.
This problem when you use like this

```
        BayesNet processes = new BayesNet();
        String options = "-D -Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 -- -P 1 -S BAYES -E weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator -- -A 0.5";
        processes.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions(options));
```

Change set all param like this.(Here not all option, small example)

```
        BayesNet processes = new BayesNet();
        SimpleEstimator newBayesNetEstimator = new SimpleEstimator();
        newBayesNetEstimator.setAlpha(0.5);
        processes.setEstimator(newBayesNetEstimator);
```

Comment: Is there a direct setter for the -M option of the RandomForest (i.e. minimum number of instances per leaf)? I see no other way than to do it indirectly via setOptions() with the above error as a result

Comment: You can do it via classifier.
```RandomForest processesTest = new RandomForest(); processesTest.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions(options)); RandomTree rt = (RandomTree) processesTest.getClassifier(); rt.setMinNum(0.2);//value processesTest.setClassifier(rt);```