# Weka RandomForest setter for -M option

Tags: java, classpath, weka

The Weka RandomForest class provides various setters, like `setNumIterations()`, `setNumFeatures()`, `setMaxDepth()`, etc. Is there also a setter to set the minimum number of instances per leaf option of a RandomForest?

I am currently setting it indirectly via `setOptions()` using `-M`, but that triggers the "Can't find a permissible class" error (see [Weka - Can't find a permissible class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61761842/1330001)) when running the program from the command-line `java -jar target/MyApp.jar`. However, running from it within the Apache Netbeans IDE does work without any errors, so perhaps some classpath/Maven change might also help?

Comment: You need to post the String array that you are supplying to the `setOptions(String[])` method to determine any potential mistakes.

Comment: @fracpete setOptions just works (inside the IDE). My question was about avoiding using it, or alternatively have a fix for the Java reflection error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest` is derived from `weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging`, with the base classifier being accessible via the `getClassifier()` method. `RandomForest` uses `weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree` as the base classifier which has the `-M` option that you mentioned.

So you could probably do something like this to change the minimum number of instances per leaf:

```java
import weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest;
import weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree;
import weka.core.Utils;

RandomForest rf = new RandomForest();
RandomTree rt = (RandomTree) rf.getClassifier();
rt.setMinNum(5);
System.out.println(Utils.toCommandLine(rf));
```

This will output something like this:

```
weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -P 100 -I 100 -num-slots 1 -K 0 -M 5.0 -V 0.001 -S 1
```